# Selenium Python Link Text-var to Value-var in subchild under different conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
<div class="_97KWR">
<div class="_12x3s">
  <div class="_1PF0y">
     <div class="_1xNd0 CTwrR _3ASIK">
        <a class="_3bf_k _1WIu4" href="/en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/gof-turkey-championship-2019-555/live/gazorpazorp/log-arena-fams-5551565"><span>Franco Pescatore</span></a>
        <div class="_2cZpo">
           <svg width="32px" height="32px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <use xlink:href="dist/icons.svg#hula-hula"></use>
           </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="_1sT8o _2ALVH">
           <div class="_2Li3l _1fAz9"><img src="/dist/disabled-gg.png" alt="Disabled gg"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="_2b9x1">
        <div>
           <svg width="18px" height="14px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <use xlink:href="dist/icons.svg#vs"></use>
           </svg>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="_1xNd0 CTwrR _3ASIK">
        <a class="_3bf_k _1WIu4" href="/en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/gof-turkey-championship-2019-555/live/gazorpazorp/log-arena-fams-5551565"><span>Giorgio Pescato</span></a><img class="_25rWl _2cZpo" alt="Giorgio Pescato" src="https://ultramedia.com/Media/GiorgioPescato_f6f84978-6da4-4e14-a36b-860dce530d08.png">
        <div class="_1sT8o _2ALVH">
           <div class="_2Li3l _1fAz9"><img src="/dist/disabled-gg.png" alt="Disabled gg"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 <div class="_1xNd0 CTwrR">
    <a class="_3bf_k _1WIu4" href="'/en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/swing/fun#4844844"> 
 <span>BipolarFun</span></a><img class="_25rWl _2cZpo" alt="BipolarFun" src="https://promedia.com/Media//en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/swing/4844844.png">
 <div class="_1sT8o _2ALVH">
   <button class="_2Li3l _1fAz9"><span>1,30</span></button>
  <div class="_1CeGR">
     <div class="_1T5lR"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And it goes dynamically in this way,
Since the class of the DIV is dynamic, I 'fixed' by using the **xpath**

> //a[starts-with(@href,'/en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/

with this I could access the Name like Franco Pescatore or Giorgio Pescato
and with **xpath**

> //button[starts-with(@class,'_')]

I could access the value, but not when it's "Disabled"

also I cannot do first ones and then the others because it doesn't return the same amount of elements, so I'm having trouble linking the Text element with the Value element which is in a subchild,

at the end the resoult should be like this:

```
n[0] = 'BipolarFun'
a[0] = 1,30
n[1] = 'Franco Pescatore'
a[1] = 0 #disabled
n[2] = 'Giorgio Pescato'
a[2] = 0 #disabled
```

please help, i'm stuck :|

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Code you can try:

```
# get all labels
labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/en/gilgamesh/hola-dola/')]")
for label in labels:
    # get buttons inside label's parent DIV
    buttons = label.find_elements_by_xpath("./ancestor::div[1]//button")
    # if buttons more than 0, then get button text else use 0.
    button_value = buttons[0].text if len(buttons) > 0 else 0
    print(f"Label: {label.text}, value: {button_value}")
```

Comment: line 79, in checkacc
    for label in labels:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: It should find_elements... Updated